# ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded successfully

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Nvidia driver was working fine on 20.04 lts, after upgrading to 22.04 lts I'm unable to install the driver, in update manager I have choosed the latest driver from nvidia then when I open the terminal and type

```
 nvidia-settings
```

It shows the following

```
(nvidia-settings:7848): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 20:36:10.048: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:7848): CRITICAL **: 20:36:10.049: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed
** Message: 20:36:10.073: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 20:36:10.073: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

and when I type `prime-select nvidia`

```
Info: selecting the nvidia profile
Deleting /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
Done
```

but the truth is nothing happened,

I have disabled Secured boot and same problem

I have looked over this links
[nvidia-driver is installed, but the driver is not loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292278/nvidia-driver-is-installed-but-the-driver-is-not-loaded)

and [ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153023/error-nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded)

My GPU is 3070 MAX-Q

I really have no idea what I should do now.

What should I trace?

Note that I have installed driver Nvidia-driver-515

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no Cog icon is not showing, where should I append this?